# reportlab dynamic data-driven header outputs wrong subtitle

Tags: python, dynamic, header, reportlab, data-driven

I have created some fictitious, though representative, clinical trial type data using Pandas, and now come to some test reporting in ReportLab.

The data has a block (~50 rows) where the treatment column is 'Placebo' and the same amount where the treatment is 'Active'. I simply want to list the data using a sub-heading of 'Treatment Group: Placebo' for the first set and 'Treatment Group: Active' for the second.

There are some hits on a similar topic, and, indeed I've used one of the suggested techniques, namely to extend the arguments of a header functions using `partial` from `functools`.

```
title1 = "ACME Corp                                                                                                              CONFIDENTIAL"
title2 = "XYZ123 / Anti-Hypertensive                                                                                                    Draft"
title3 = "Protocol XYZ123"

title4 = "Study XYZ123"
title5 = "Listing of Demographic Data by Treatment Arm"
title6 = "All subjects"
def title(canvas, doc, bytext):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont(styleN.fontName, styleN.fontSize)
    canvas.drawString(DOCMARGIN, PAGE_HEIGHT*.975, title1)
    canvas.drawString(DOCMARGIN, PAGE_HEIGHT*.950, title2)
    canvas.drawString(DOCMARGIN, PAGE_HEIGHT*.925, title3)
    canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT*.900, title4)
    canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT*.875, title5)
    canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT*.850, title6)
    canvas.drawString(DOCMARGIN, PAGE_HEIGHT*.825, "Treatment Group:" + bytext)
    canvas.restoreState()
```

This is then called as follows. `n_groups` has the value of 2 from a summary query and 0 maps to 'Placebo' and 1 maps to active.

```
def build_pdf(doc): 
    ptemplates = []
    for armcd in range(n_groups):
        ptemplates.append(PageTemplate(id = 'PT' + str(armcd), frames = [dataFrame,],
                     onPage = partial(title, bytext=t_dict[armcd]),
                     onPageEnd = foot))
    doc.addPageTemplates(ptemplates)

    elements = []
    for armcd in range(n_groups):
        elements.append(NextPageTemplate('PT' + str(armcd)))  
        sublist = [t for t in lista if t[0] == (armcd+1)]
        sublist.insert(0,colheads)
        data_table = Table(sublist, 6*[40*mm], len(sublist)*[DATA_CELL_HEIGHT], repeatRows=1)
        data_table.setStyle(styleC)
        elements.append(data_table)
        elements.append(PageBreak())
    doc.build(elements)
```

The report produces 6 pages. The first 3 pages of placebo data are correct, pages 5 & 6 of active data are correct, but page 4 - which should be the first page of the second 'active' group has the sub-title 'Treatment Group: Placebo'.

I have re-organized the order of the statements multiple times, but can't get Page 4 to sub-title correctly. Any help, suggestions or magic would be much appreciated.

[Edit 1: sample data structure]
The 'top' of the data starts as:

```
[
   [1, 'Placebo', '000001-000015', '1976-09-20', 33, 'F', 'Black'],
   [1, 'Placebo', '000001-000030', '1959-04-26', 50, 'M', 'Asian'],
   [1, 'Placebo', '000001-000031', '1946-02-07', 64, 'F', 'Asian'],
   [1, 'Placebo', '000001-000046', '1947-11-08', 62, 'M', 'Asian'],
```

etc for 50 rows, then continues with

```
   [2, 'Active', '000001-000002', '1962-02-28', 48, 'F', 'Black'],
   [2, 'Active', '000001-000008', '1975-10-20', 34, 'M', 'Black'],
   [2, 'Active', '000001-000013', '1959-01-19', 51, 'M', 'White'],
   [2, 'Active', '000001-000022', '1962-01-12', 48, 'F', 'Black'],
   [2, 'Active', '000001-000036', '1976-10-17', 33, 'F', 'Asian'],
   [2, 'Active', '000001-000045', '1980-12-31', 29, 'F', 'White'],
```

for another 50.

The column header inserted is:

```
['Treatment Arm Code',
        'Treatment Arm',
        'Site ID - Subject ID',
        'Date of Birth',
        'Age (Years)',
        'Gender',
        'Ethnicity'],
```

[Edit 2: A solution - move the `PageBreak()` and make it conditional:]

```
def build_pdf(doc): 
    ptemplates = []
    for armcd in range(n_groups):
        ptemplates.append(PageTemplate(id = 'PT' + str(armcd), frames = [dataFrame,],
                     onPage = partial(title, bytext=t_dict[armcd]),
                     onPageEnd = foot))
    doc.addPageTemplates(ptemplates)

    elements = []
    for armcd in range(n_groups):     
        elements.append(NextPageTemplate('PT' + str(armcd)))
        if armcd > 0:
            elements.append(PageBreak())
        sublist = [t for t in lista if t[0] == (armcd+1)]
        sublist.insert(0,colheads)
        data_table = Table(sublist, 6*[40*mm], len(sublist)*[DATA_CELL_HEIGHT], repeatRows=1)
        data_table.setStyle(styleC)
        elements.append(data_table)

    doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: It is a good first question, but for someone to be able to help you effectively it is likely that you need to provide the (possibly dummy) input data.  Without it it will be very hard to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sample data added. I hope it helps.

Comment: Interestingly, if I execute the second iteration of the loop separately, the last 3 pages come out perfectly.

Comment: I shall examine the list used as argument to the build method when the groups are executed together and when executed separately.

Comment: Solved. I had to move the position of the PageBreak() to just below the NextPageTemplate call and stop it happening during the first iteration. But I have no idea why I needed to do this in order to get the correct titles to appear against the correct block of data.